# reuse jquery html selectors loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I am looking for best practice to use jquery loop.

I have a jquery loop, like this:

```
$.each(rows, function(){
  var rowClass = $.trim(this);
  $('table.' + o.MainTableClass).append('<tr class="'+rowClass+'" />');
  $('.'+rowClass).find('.ItemRow').each(function(){
    var date = $(this).find('span.Date').text().split(o.dateSpliter).pop();
    if($.inArray(date,usedYears)==-1)
    {
      usedYears.push(date);
    }
  });
});
```

The idea is, that i have to reuse this loop again except this part:

```
if($.inArray(date,usedYears)==-1)
{
  usedYears.push(date);
}
```

I mean pretty much everything what is in second loop. I can just **"copy/paste"**  an use the same loop again, but I am feeling that it is not the best practice to go this way.

Maybe I can cash this loop, or drop into some function, what do you suggest me to use in this case ?

Thanks

Comment: Place this code in a function with an optional callback. If the callback exists, pass each iteration through the callback for processing, otherwise just continue on. (Though, I'm not 100% positive what it is you're trying to achieve here).

Answer (score 0):

Use a function instead, send date and usedYears and get both as return params.

Comment: I mean the main function gets a callback and calls that sending date and UsedYears to.

Answer (score 0):

Define a higher-order function:

```
function eachRow(func) {
  $.each(rows, function() {
    var rowClass = $.trim(this);
    $('table.' + o.MainTableClass).append('<tr class="' + rowClass + '" />');
    $('.' + rowClass).find('.ItemRow').each(function() {
      var date = $(this).find('span.Date').text().split(o.dateSpliter).pop();
      func(date);
  });
});
```

Then:

```
var usedYears = [];
eachRow(function (date) {
  if($.inArray(date,usedYears)==-1)
  {
      usedYears.push(date);
  }
});
```

To re-use:

```
eachRow( function (date) {
  //do stuff with date.
});
```

You can pass more stuff into func if you need to use it.